# Prevent date conversion in list append in R

Tags: r, list, date, type-conversion

If I run this code I end up with date object in my list

```
smpl_date <- as.Date('2013-02-01')
smpl_list <- c(smpl_date)
print(smpl_list)
```

out:

```
"2013-02-01"
```

However, if I run this code, I end up with something different

```
smpl_date <- as.Date('2013-02-01')
smpl_list <- c()
smpl_list <- c(smpl_list, smpl_date)
print(smpl_list)
```

out:

```
15737
```

How can I prevent conversion in last case?

Comment: Don't use a NULL (`c()`) for the leading value.  It doesn't make much sense to do that anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea is that you want both things that you are combining with `c` to be the same so as to avoid implicit conversion to a common class. In this case, that suggests that you want `smpl_list` to start as an empty `Date`. That turns out to be more difficult than I would have expected, but e.g.,

```
smpl_date <- as.Date('2013-02-01')
smpl_list <- Sys.Date()[0]
smpl_list <- c(smpl_list, smpl_date)
print(smpl_list)
```

will do it.